# process exits after getting command from pipe

Tags: linux, pipe, exit, named-pipes

On Ubuntu, I start a command line program (gnu backgammon) and let it get its commands from a pipe (commandpipe), like so

```
$ gnubg -t < commandpipe
```

from another terminal, I do

```
$ echo "new game" > commandpipe
```

This works fine, a new game is started, **but** after the program has finished processing that command, the process exits.

How can I prevent the backgammon process from exiting? I would like to continue sending commands to it via the commandpipe.

Answer (score 0):

This is only because you used `echo`, which immediately quits after echoing. I believe when a program quits its file descriptors are closed. (OK, it's not an actual program in bash, it's a builtin, but I don't think this matters.) If you wrote an actual interactive program, e.g. with a GUI (and remember, StackOverflow is for programming questions, not Unix questions, which belong over [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)) and redirected its stdout to the named pipe, you would not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reader gets EOF and thus closes the FIFO. So you need a loop, like this:

```
$ while (true); do cat myfifo; done | ts
jan 05 23:01:56 a
jan 05 23:01:58 b
```

And in another terminal:

```
$ echo a > myfifo 
$ echo b > myfifo
```

Substitute `ts` with `gnubg -t`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file descriptor is closed, and when the last write file descriptor is closed, it sends a signal to the read process.

As a quick hack, you can do this:

```
cat < z  # read process in one terminal
cat > z &  # Keep write File Descriptor open. Put in background (or run in new terminal)
echo hi > z  # This will close the FD, but not signal the end of input
```

But you should really be writing in a real programming language where you can control your file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid EOF, you could use `tail`:

```
tail -f commandpipe | gnubg -t
```